# Changing items of bottom navigation bar in android

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview, android-bottomnavigationview

I wanted to add more than 5 items in the bottom navigation but it allows only 5 items. So I thought to add the screen from where user can change the items at the bottom navigation whichever he wants. I have seen this kind of behaviour in IOS application but haven't seen in any andorid app. is it possible?

Comment: If my answer helps you then please mark as a right my answer from tick mark otherwise i'm gonna remove this answer brother : https://www.google.com/search?q=right+mark+as+an+answer+stackoverflow&sxsrf=ACYBGNQVsfXj9VeT9WRKWerxeSRoAMe2uQ:1579936139192&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiQk-DimJ7nAhWBc30KHdm9CGAQ_AUoAXoECAwQAw&biw=1517&bih=730#imgrc=9_JN49MpzDykBM:

Answer (score 0):

You can now add more than 5 tabs , There’s an easy way to do it now: Use Support Library 28 and just add `app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"` to your `BottomNavigationView` XML declaration. or you can create a custom BottomNavigationView by creating your own XML layout. first try below code snippet.

Try out this solution: 
[Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44178223/3974530)

This exaple also helps you: [Exaple](https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar)

Hope this may helps you